# Laravel 5 Array to View

Tags: laravel-5

Can some please tell me how to display the results of this array in a view in Laravel 5?

```
RowCollection {#464 ▼
  #title: "Worksheet"
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => CellCollection {#472 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Owen Kelley"
        "age" => 29.0
      ]
    }
    1 => CellCollection {#473 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Jim Jackson"
        "age" => 50.0
      ]
    }
    2 => CellCollection {#474 ▼
      #title: null
      #items: array:2 [▼
        "name" => "Sally Anne"
        "age" => 35.0
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been struggling with this for ages!

Many thanks.

Comment: Show us your controller function, and your view name, we will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use foreach, example:

**In controller/routes.php:**

```
return view('yourviewname')->with('elephants', 'elephants')
```

**In blade view:**

```
@foreach($elephants as $elephant)
{{ $elephant->name }}
@endforeach
```